# Function setenv() not found?

Tags: c++

why is this feature not visible in a simple console application c++ vs2017.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // setenv here or <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
    //...
}
```

> setenv error C3861: identifier not found

Comment: As far as I can find using online references, `setenv` is defined in `stdlib.h` but not in `cstdlib`... just include the C header instead, using `extern "C"` ?

Comment: There is no such function in the C++ standard, only `getenv`.

Comment: ok. unfortunately stdlib.h and extern "C" wrapper did not help(

Comment: I temporarily use this solution:
int setenv_my(const char *name, const char *value, int rewrite)
{
 std::stringstream sstr;
 sstr << name << '=' << value;
 return _putenv(sstr.str().c_str());
}

Comment: You shouldn't. You should use a standard header from somewher. Don't write software using 1000 crutches.